# Cannot find Logstash Index in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, kibana, syslog

I am trying to setup a central Logging solution for Syslog-UDP Logging data with ELK stack in the docker environment.

I tried to setup a docker-compose.yml with the oss versions of the ELK-Stack. After firing docker-compose up, I expected to see the Logstash Index on the kibana interface under "Stack Management" => "Index Patterns", but there is no Index to be found.

**Problem:**

After starting all three containers (elastic, logstash, kibana) my Logstash Index doesnt seem to appear in the kibana web-interface.

Software:

- Host-System: Windows 10
- Docker: Docker-Desktop 4.5.1 (74721)

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  # Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/docker.html
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2
    container_name: ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - amb_kibana
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1g
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:7.10.2
    container_name: ambulance_kibana_logstash
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/:/logstash_dir
    command: logstash -f /logstash_dir/logstash.conf
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9600:9600"
      - "514:514/udp"
    networks:
      - amb_kibana
  # Kibana: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:7.10.2
    container_name: ambulance_kibana
    environment:
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://host.docker.internal:9200"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - amb_kibana
networks:
  amb_kibana:
    driver: bridge
```

**logstash.conf:**

```
input {
    udp {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 514
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    }
}
```

Console-Output after docker-compose up:

```
Creating ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch ... done
Creating ambulance_kibana               ... done
Creating ambulance_kibana_logstash      ... done
Attaching to ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch, ambulance_kibana_logstash, ambulance_kibana
ambulance_kibana_logstash | Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
ambulance_kibana_logstash | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:22,827Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "version[7.10.2], pid[8], build[oss/docker/747e1cc71def077253878a59143c1f785afa92b9/2021-01-13T00:42:
12.435326Z], OS[Linux/4.19.128-microsoft-standard/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/15.0.1/15.0.1+9]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:22,831Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk], using bundled JDK [true]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:22,832Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.tt
l=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirec
tArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, -Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:G1ReservePercent=25, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-12772762765856285752, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=d
ata, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xmx512m, -Xms512m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=268435456, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/confi
g, -Des.distribution.flavor=oss, -Des.distribution.type=docker, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,268Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,268Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [analysis-common]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,268Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [geo]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,269Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [ingest-common]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,269Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [ingest-geoip]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,271Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [ingest-user-agent]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,272Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [kibana]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,272Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [lang-expression]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,272Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [lang-mustache]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,272Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [lang-painless]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,273Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [mapper-extras]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,274Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [parent-join]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,274Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [percolator]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,274Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [rank-eval]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,274Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [reindex]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,275Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [repository-url]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,276Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "loaded module [transport-netty4]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,283Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "no plugins loaded" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,358Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (overlay)]], net usable_space [218.2gb], net total_space
 [250.9gb], types [overlay]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,359Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "heap size [512mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:24,452Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "node name [1bd1af51a22e], node ID [vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw], cluster name [docker-cluster], roles [ma
ster, remote_cluster_client, data, ingest]" }
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:26Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":7,"message":"Plugin \"visTypeXy\" is disabled."}
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:26Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":7,"message":"Setting up [40] plugins: [usageCollection,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetry,kibanaUsageCollection,securityOss,newsfeed,mapsLegacy,kibanaLegacy,share,legacyExport,embeddable,expressions,dat
a,home,console,apmOss,management,indexPatternManagement,advancedSettings,savedObjects,dashboard,visualizations,visTypeVega,visTypeTimelion,timelion,visTypeTable,visTypeMarkdown,tileMap,regionMap,inputControlVis,visualize,esUiShared,charts,visTypeVislib,visTypeTimeseries,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeMetric,discover,sa
vedObjectsManagement,bfetch]"}
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:27Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":7,"message":"Waiting until all Elasticsearch nodes are compatible with Kibana before starting saved objects migrations..."}
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:27Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":7,"message":"[ConnectionError]: socket hang up"}
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:27Z","tags":["error","savedobjects-service"],"pid":7,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes."}
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:29,633Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.t.NettyAllocator", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=unpooled, suggested_max_allocati
on_size=256kb, factors={es.unsafe.use_unpooled_allocator=null, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=1mb, heap_size=512mb}]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:29,749Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.d.DiscoveryModule", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "using discovery type [single-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]" }
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:29Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":7,"message":"[ConnectionError]: socket hang up"}
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:30,206Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be autom
atically detected or imported and must be managed manually" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:30,507Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "initialized" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:30,508Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "starting ..." }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:30,692Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.t.TransportService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "publish_address {192.168.96.2:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:31,018Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.c.Coordinator", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "setting initial configuration to VotingConfiguration{vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw}" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:31,171Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.s.MasterService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[{1bd1af51a22e}{vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw}{uaKJzBE9Qhqst
6ENFzsJ0A}{192.168.96.2}{192.168.96.2:9300}{dimr} elect leader, _BECOME_MASTER_TASK_, _FINISH_ELECTION_], term: 1, version: 1, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{1bd1af51a22e}{vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw}{uaKJzBE9Qhqst6ENFzsJ0A}{192.168.96.2}{192.168.96.2:9300}{dimr}]}" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:31,243Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.c.CoordinationState", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "cluster UUID set to [xHujkBpFSeiR_6uHyalNdg]" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:31,314Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "master node changed {previous [], current [{1bd1af51a22e}{vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw}
{uaKJzBE9Qhqst6ENFzsJ0A}{192.168.96.2}{192.168.96.2:9300}{dimr}]}, term: 1, version: 1, reason: Publication{term=1, version=1}" }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:31,340Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "publish_address {192.168.96.2:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}", "cluste
r.uuid": "xHujkBpFSeiR_6uHyalNdg", "node.id": "vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw"  }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:31,340Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "started", "cluster.uuid": "xHujkBpFSeiR_6uHyalNdg", "node.id": "vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw"  }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:31,368Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.g.GatewayService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "recovered [0] indices into cluster_state", "cluster.uuid": "xHujkBpFSeiR_6uHyalNdg", "node
.id": "vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw"  }
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:32Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":7,"message":"Starting saved objects migrations"}
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:32Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":7,"message":"Creating index .kibana_1."}
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:33,090Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.m.MetadataCreateIndexService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "[.kibana_1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [1]/[1]", "clu
ster.uuid": "xHujkBpFSeiR_6uHyalNdg", "node.id": "vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw"  }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:33,107Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "updating number_of_replicas to [0] for indices [.kibana_1]", "cluster.uuid": "xHujk
BpFSeiR_6uHyalNdg", "node.id": "vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw"  }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:33,680Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.
kibana_1][0]]]).", "cluster.uuid": "xHujkBpFSeiR_6uHyalNdg", "node.id": "vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw"  }
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:33Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":7,"message":"Pointing alias .kibana to .kibana_1."}
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:33Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":7,"message":"Finished in 1376ms."}
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:34Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":7,"message":"Starting [40] plugins: [usageCollection,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetry,kibanaUsageCollection,securityOss,newsfeed,mapsLegacy,kibanaLegacy,share,legacyExport,embeddable,expressions,data,
home,console,apmOss,management,indexPatternManagement,advancedSettings,savedObjects,dashboard,visualizations,visTypeVega,visTypeTimelion,timelion,visTypeTable,visTypeMarkdown,tileMap,regionMap,inputControlVis,visualize,esUiShared,charts,visTypeVislib,visTypeTimeseries,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeMetric,discover,save
dObjectsManagement,bfetch]"}
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:34Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":7,"message":"Server running at http://0:5601"}
ambulance_kibana | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-04-04T14:01:34Z","tags":["info","http","server","Kibana"],"pid":7,"message":"http server running at http://0:5601"}
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:34,698Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.m.MetadataMappingService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "[.kibana_1/8CKId7l_T0iddC74lgNj-w] update_mapping [_doc]", "cluster.uuid": "xHuj
kBpFSeiR_6uHyalNdg", "node.id": "vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw"  }
ambulance_kibana_logstash | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
ambulance_kibana_logstash | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper (file:/tmp/jruby-1/jruby2086728291139417056jopenssl.jar) to field java.security.MessageDigest.provider
ambulance_kibana_logstash | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper
ambulance_kibana_logstash | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
ambulance_kibana_logstash | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
ambulance_kibana_logstash | Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:40,318][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.10.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10 on 11.0.8+10 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:40,362][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:40,375][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:40,661][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:40,687][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"cd04a6bf-9615-45e3-be8d-172faa7274bd", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:42,016][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 32 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 23 keys and 47 values 
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:42,410][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired E
CS Compatibility mode.
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:42,815][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:42,997][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:43,054][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:43,058][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:43,083][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch:9200"]}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:43,145][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:43,174][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, "pipeline.sources"=>["/logstash_dir/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Th
read:0x3c182f72 run>"}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:43,200][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Index Lifecycle Management is set to 'auto', but will be disabled - Index Lifecycle management is not installed on your Elasticsearch cluster
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:43,202][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"messag
e_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@ti
mestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:43,234][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Installing elasticsearch template to _template/logstash
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-04T14:01:43,318Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.m.MetadataIndexTemplateService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "1bd1af51a22e", "message": "adding template [logstash] for index patterns [logstash-*]", "cluster.uuid
": "xHujkBpFSeiR_6uHyalNdg", "node.id": "vjcbyWJMTn2Xcopkbx_HXw"  }
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:43,925][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.75}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:43,948][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:44,008][INFO ][logstash.inputs.udp      ][main][62a945d698b51a6132bd05e47e528d6c402f8383ef39403f40bf57020a0a2dfc] Starting UDP listener {:address=>"127.0.0.1:514"}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:44,012][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:44,053][INFO ][logstash.inputs.udp      ][main][62a945d698b51a6132bd05e47e528d6c402f8383ef39403f40bf57020a0a2dfc] UDP listener started {:address=>"127.0.0.1:514", :receive_buffer_bytes=>"106496", :queue_size=>"2000"}
ambulance_kibana_logstash | [2022-04-04T14:01:44,225][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

I would appreciate if someone can give me clue whats going wrong. Also this is my first ever stackoverflow question. Feedback is highly welcome

Comment: I believe you need to [create the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.17/index-patterns.html) by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I tried the steps from the documentation you linked, but the underlying problems seems to be that there are no matching indices. Kibana doesnt find any indices for logstash or similar entries from elasticsearch. I believe there may be a connection problem between elasticsearch and kibana, but I cant quite figure it out.

Comment: You are binding your logstash input to `127.0.0.1`, this means that logstash will only receive data from localhost, which means the container itself. Try to change it and bind to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I changed that. But the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by simply sending logs to logstash. As soon as the first logs arrived, elasticsearch automatically created the logstash index.

```
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "deprecation", "timestamp": "2022-04-05T09:28:46,990Z", "level": "DEPRECATION", "component": "o.e.d.a.b.BulkRequestParser", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "b1f1e50666ff", "message": "[types removal] Specifying types in bulk requests is deprecated.", "clu
ster.uuid": "sm_xQ8ZwTFG3JKWfsxkZuQ", "node.id": "XSvHBxFaRSWLercYGL1x-g"  }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-05T09:28:47,010Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.m.MetadataCreateIndexService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "b1f1e50666ff", "message": "[logstash-2022.04.05] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [log
stash], shards [1]/[1]", "cluster.uuid": "sm_xQ8ZwTFG3JKWfsxkZuQ", "node.id": "XSvHBxFaRSWLercYGL1x-g"  }
ambulance_kibana_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-04-05T09:28:47,363Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.m.MetadataMappingService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "b1f1e50666ff", "message": "[logstash-2022.04.05/bCLws1k0Sziu-2wwPJoxqw] update_mapping [_doc]", "cluster.uu
id": "sm_xQ8ZwTFG3JKWfsxkZuQ", "node.id": "XSvHBxFaRSWLercYGL1x-g"  }
```

[logstash index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjanc.jpg)

Thanks for the help in the comments.